# What is the structure of 我吃饭的时候看了一本书?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

The sentence 我吃饭的时候看了一本书。 apparently has two verbs (吃 and 看), but I can’t see how the two actions are correlated. Could anyone explain that?

Comment: 我一边吃饭一边看书。“我吃饭的时候(我)看了一本书” 感觉怪怪的，好像病句一样

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are familiar with 的时候 but this translates approximately to 'while'.

So the sentence reads:

*While I was **eating** I **read** a book.*

You can see the English use "I" twice, so it may make more sense to you if you read it like this:

我吃饭的时候(我)看了一本书

Answer (score 4):

A verb works with an object. In this sentence, the first verb 吃 (have or eat) works with 饭 (meal), and the second, 看 (read) works with 书 (book), and "...的时候..." (while) links two phrases together.

Answer (score 2):

“我吃饭的时候”是个状语从句，不知道你们能不能看懂,"when 我吃的的时候，我看了一本书"

“我吃饭的时候” has an [adverbial clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause) (I'm not sure if you can understand that). **When** 我吃的的时候，我看了一本书.

Answer (score 1):

I read a book while having dinner.

You can see 吃 as an [adverbial clause of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause).

Comment: So in this words, there is a verb and a adverbial clauses of time, not two verbs.

Answer (score 1):

Can't type in Chinese so I'll use pinyin.

Literally, it goes: `wo3 chi1 fan4` ("I eat/ am eating/ ate/ was eating etc.), `de5 shi2 hou5` (POS "time"), `kan4 le5 yi1 ben3 shu1` ("saw/ had seen/ read/ had read one  book").

Therefore, it roughly translates to "At the time when I was eating, I read a book."

Comment: you could maybe add the tonic accent to your pinyin. Something like `wo3 chi1 fan4`. Welcome to chinese stackexchange :-)